# webkitSpeechRecognition automatically stops

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, speech-recognition

I am using webkitSpeechRecognition. But when recognition is initiated, it stops after 1-2 mins of inactivity. I am trying to firing it back after it is ended. When I execute start_transcript(language), it keeps producing a thousand of console.log("voice recognition terminated"); and it does not recongnize anymore.

```
var final_transcript = '';
var recognizing = false;
var start_timestamp;
if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
  upgrade();
} else {
  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.interimResults = true;
  recognition.onstart = function() {
    recognizing = true;
  };

  recognition.onend = function() {
    console.log("voice recognition terminated");
    recognition.start();
  };

function start_transcript(language) {
  if (recognizing) {
    recognition.stop();
    return;
  }
  final_transcript = '';
  var rec_lang = 'fr-FR';
    recognition.lang = rec_lang;
  recognition.start();
}
```

Any help and advice will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just some tiny missings here and there. Updated your code with filling those missing gaps,Try this in your console. Also don't forget to call `start_transcript`.

```js
var final_transcript = '';
var recognizing = false;
var start_timestamp;
if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
  upgrade();
} else {
  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.interimResults = true;
  recognition.onstart = function() {
    recognizing = true;
  };

  // need to have result as well 
  recognition.onresult = function(e) {
    console.log(e.results);

    // Extracting the words from the result and printing in the console 
    var transcript = [...e.results]
      .map(result => result[0])
      .map(result => result.transcript)
      .join('');
    console.log(transcript);
  };

  recognition.onend = function() {
    console.log("voice recognition terminated");
    recognition.start();
  };
} // I guess you forgot closing the else block as well

function start_transcript() {
  if (recognizing) {
    recognition.stop();
    return;
  }
  final_transcript = '';
  var rec_lang = 'fr-FR';
  recognition.lang = rec_lang;
  recognition.start();
}
```

PS: Also I had made a similar kind of project by referring Wesbos's javascript30, and mixed it with webpack. If you want to refer it then please visit  https://github.com/Mondal10/personal-voice-assistant

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I tried your code, but it spines my app in countless "voice recognition terminated" console logs.